# Encrypted Oracle-Ds.xml and decryption in jdbc code

Tags: encryption, jdbc, jboss

Server :JBOSS 5.x
Following function is written in my session bean(ejb3 architecture)

```
@Remote(OracleDsInteractionRemote.class)
@Local(OracleDsInteractionLocal.class)

@Stateless
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="OracleDsInteractionBean/remote")
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding="OracleDsInteractionBean/local")

public class OracleDsInteractionBean implements OracleDsInteractionRemote,OracleDsInteractionLocal
{
@EJB    
@Resource(mappedName="java:/EncryptedDS") 
private DataSource ds1;

 public int getAllValues() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("************************* ");
    Connection conn = ds1.getConnection();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM DETAILS_DATA";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next())
    {
        return rs.getInt(1);
    }
    return -1;

}
}
```

This function is retrieving number of rows from details_data table using jdbc connection. DataSource Object ds1 is mapped with 'EncryptedDS'. Entry of 'EncryptedDS' is defined in oracle-ds.xml as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!-- ===================================================================== -->
 <!--                                                                       -->
 <!--  JBoss Server Configuration                                           -->
 <datasources>
   <xa-datasource>
     <jndi-name>EncryptedDS</jndi-name>
     <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>

     <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@182.158.93.26:1521:dbSid</xa-datasource-property>

     <xa-datasource-property name="User">Test</xa-datasource-property>
     <xa-datasource-property name="Password">pass123</xa-datasource-property>

     <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>

        <metadata>
           <type-mapping>Oracle11g</type-mapping>
        </metadata>
    </xa-datasource>
   </datasources>
```

But problem is that anyone can go to $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy directory and find out 'EncryptedDS' configuration from oracle-ds.xml.. (In oracle-ds.xml complete database information is written in text(DatabaseServerIP,Port,Sid,SchemaName,SchemaPassword))...
How can i store encrypted database information in oracle-ds.xml? How my java code will decode that for making jdbc connection?

Comment: Can't you just encrypt the password?

Comment: @CoolBeans : try to be more clear, i'm in lack of ideas in this problem, even it sounds like a classic..I have spent hours looking for tutorials on Google.However I cannot seem to find anything that holds the hand, they all tend to be descriptions of encryption-decryption technology...Can u direct me to some example that cover this?

Comment: See this http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Encrypting_Data_Source_Passwords.html